# Filtrar por fecha PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, date, timestamp

Buenas a tod@s.

Estoy intentando hacer una Select filtrando unicamente por fecha en una BBDD con MySQL, en formato de columna timestamp, donde se insertan los datos con este formato ('Y-m-d H:i:s').

Las fechas las recibo de este formulario:

```
            Filtrar Registros por dia :<br>
     <form action='<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>'  method='POST'>
           <p>23 Noviembre <input type='radio' name='dia' value='2016-11-23'/></p>
           <p>24 Noviembre <input type='radio' name='dia'value='2016-11-24'/></p>
           <p><input type=submit name='filtrar'  VALUE=Filtrar></p>
     </form>
            Filtrar Registros por hora:<br>
     <form action='<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>'  method='POST'>
          <p>16:00 H<input type='radio' name='hora' value='16:00:00'/></p>
          <p>17:00 H<input type='radio' name='hora' value='17:00:00'/></p>
          <p>18:00 H<input type='radio' name='hora' value='18:00:00'/></p>
          <p><input type=submit  name='filtrar1' VALUE=Filtrar></p>
     </form>
```

Paso los datos a PHP de esta manera para hacer la Select:

```
          if ( !isset($_POST['filtrar'])  || !isset($_POST['dia']) ){}else{                       
                      $date =$_POST['dia'];
                      $now = new DateTime($date);
                      $hoy=$now->format('Y-m-d'); 
                      echo "<h1>".$hoy."</h1>";
$registros=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM `nom_tab` WHERE `Fecha` = '$hoy'")
   or die('Problemas al buscar'. mysqli_error());
   } 
    $row_cnt = $registros->num_rows;
```

Si la consulta funciona muestro los datos en una tabla .

Mi pregunta es:

Qué o Comó, puedo hacer para filtrar unicamente por ('Y-m-d')?

Ya que MySQL espera que le pase ('Y-m-d H:i:s').

Desde ya Gracias por todo .
Saludos.

Comment: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL no se espera que le des la hora, es más espera un string para ordernarlo y compararlo, por lo que esto es válido:

`"SELECT * FROM nom_tab WHERE Fecha > '2016-01-00'"`

Así sacarías todos los registros de nom_tab que tenga la fecha mayor que 2016-01-00: Empezaría desde el 01 de Enero del 2016 a las 00:00:00.

**En tu caso, yo haría la sentencia SQL de la siguiente forma:**

`"SELECT * FROM nom_tab WHERE Fecha BETWEEN '$hoy' AND '$hoy 23:59:59'"`

Espero que te ayude.

Un Saludo.

Edito: La respues de "Ricardo Fernandez" es buena, pero un CAST come recursos de MySQL innecesariamente (por lo menos en esta ocasión).

Comment: Gracias Slash . He tomado nota de tus comentarios y junto con los de Ricardo he solucionado el problema.

Comment: De nada. Recuerda poner una de las dos soluciones como "Solución". Y si tienes una mejor o alguna intermedio o lo que sea, respóndete y ponla como "Solución"

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que simplemente haciendo:

```
$registros = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM nom_tab WHERE Fecha >= '$hoy 00:00:00'AND Fecha <= '$hoy 23:59:59'");
```

o bien:

```
 $registros = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM nom_tab WHERE CAST(
Fecha AS DATE)= '$hoy'");
```

Comment: Gracias Ricardo. Me ha sido de gran ayuda.

Comment: hola a todos me podrian ayudar con un problema similar?